# Image.file items for a ListView or GridView disappear when scrolling back and forth

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to populate a ListView with Image.file widgets using Image Picker.

[image]

I tried setting cacheExtent to 9999. but it doesn't make a difference, this behavior doesn't occur in CachedNetworkImage, but sadly this is a file image so is there a way to replicate said behavior?

Sample Code:

```
GridView.builder(
        cacheExtent: 9999,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: images.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 1,
          mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          final image = images[index];
          return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
            print(constraints);
            return (image != null)
                ? ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                    child: Image.file(
                      File(image.path),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      cacheWidth: constraints.biggest.width.ceil(),
                      cacheHeight: constraints.biggest.height.ceil(),
                    ),
                  )
              : const SizedBox.shrink();
        },
      ),
```

When i use cacheWidth and cacheHeight it makes the loaded images pixelated and they never load in full quality
[image]

**EDIT:** it turned out to be because the loaded files were larger than needed, even though i used ImagePicker to compress their quality to 25%

As [@pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) instructed, i set the cacheWidth property to the following:

```
cacheWidth: constraints.biggest.width.ceil() * MediaQueryData.devicePixelRatio
```

Comment: seems that your first image file (with index == 0) is a huge one compared to other and it takes so long to decode it

Comment: @pskink this gif is a bad example but when the number of pictures increases the behavior starts to be more noticeable, regardless of image size

Comment: how big is it? is it one MB or so? tried `cacheWidth` and `cacheHeight` in `Image.file` constructor?

Comment: @pskink maybe less than 1MB since i use Image Picker to compress the images by 75%, cacheWidth and cacheHeight makes it display a list of pixelated images, and they never load in full quality

Comment: you dont need full quality if your image size is for example 2000x1500 and you want to show it on a widget with much smaller size (for example 200x150) - in that case use `cacheWidth: 200` and `cacheHeight: 150` or maybe a little bit more

Comment: just for testing: if you return `LayoutBuilder` from `itemBuilder` and add `print(constraints);` what do you see on the logs?

Comment: @pskink that's fair for the example i've provided, but what if i want to display the images in full quality? in another screen i'm using a ListView to do exactly that, and the images vary in aspect ratio so i can't set cacheWidth and cacheHeight dynamically

Comment: *"so i can't set cacheWidth and cacheHeight dynamically"* - you can: what does `LayoutBuilder` say?

Comment: @pskink BoxConstraints(w=168.0, h=168.0)

Comment: @pskink the load times decreased a bit but not entirely, and now for some reason, the images are stretched out, even though i set it to BoxFit.cover

Comment: ok your view size (i mean size of `Image.file` widget) is 168x168 pixels, what is the size of images you want to show? and maybe try to set only `cacheWidth`, not both `cacheWidth` and `cacheHeight`

Comment: @pskink i want to show them in that size, but cropped not stretched aka BoxFit.cover, and even though the widget size is 168x168, the pictures displayed are still very pixelated, no idea why, i've set both to constraints.biggest

Comment: post you current code then

Comment: @pskink i've updated the post

Comment: @pskink It's perfect! no stretching and no pixelation, there is still some tiny load time when scrolling back and forth, but i haven't tried this in release yet, thanks a lot.

Comment: @pskink i want to mark this as a solution but i don't know how

Comment: @psink it's 3.0

Comment: @pskink yeah, makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

Can you try update this code ?

```
Image.file(File(image.path), cacheHeight: 80, cacheWidth: 80,);
```

Comment: Just tried it, it makes images pixelated, and they never load in full quality, will attach an image to the post

Comment: I think you will need caculate size display on screen, we don't need show full quality. Only need show enough size on screen.  
example: `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/3`